# Cypress - Passing fixture alias to intercept method in version 9 and above

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, cypress, cypress-intercept

Could someone please help me with passing fixture alias to intercept method in Cypress v 9.0. I remember using the following syntax in Cypress ~4 with route method as
`cy.route("GET", "**/users/*", "@users")` where @users is a fixture defined as `cy.fixture('users.json').as('users')`

Since the cy.route is deprecated and we switched to using cy.intercept,  I cannot seem to find the right syntax for passing fixture alias to the intercept method. I would like to know if the following syntax is possible `cy.intercept("GET", "**/users/*", "@users")`

Any help is kindly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a configuration to use an aliased fixture with intercept.

You can however, use the fixture name explicitly

```js
cy.intercept("GET", "**/users/*", {fixture:'users.json'})   // pattern for fixture use
```

Given the fixture is now named in the `staticResponse` object, you ***may*** be able to use the alias there (but I don't see it documented)

```js
cy.intercept("GET", "**/users/*", {fixture:'@users'})     // may not work
```

If you have a specific need to use an aliased value, this pattern is equivalent

```js
cy.get('@alias').then(data => {
  cy.intercept("GET", "**/users/*", {body:data})     // set data staticResponse body
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Fody for your suggestions. The second option did not work as you mentioned. I am planning to use the option 1 from your suggestion.